# List of active directory group members that are not disabled

Tags: powershell, command-line, active-directory, command-prompt, dsquery

I've been trying to locate / write a script that displays all NON disabled accounts in an active directory group.

The closest I've come to a working script displays all members of a group but it also shows the disabled users.

Here's the non-filtered query.

```
dsquery group -name "admins" | dsget group -members -expand
```

Please help,
-Rob

Comment: I just found this to filter all active members of a group. I don't know how to add the two commands together.  If I even can.

  **dsquery * -filter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you tagged this with PowerShell, I will lean that direction with my answer.
If you are have the ActiveDirectory module from the AD DS RSAT tools installed (using PowerShell 3.0 or greater here)

```
Get-ADGroupMember "CN=Group DN,OU=Group OU,DC=domain,DC=com" | ? ObjectClass -eq "User" | Get-ADUser | ? Enabled
```

If you want to recourse through nested groups, use the `-Recursive` parameter on the `Get-ADGroupMember` cmdlet.